# How to grant access to only one perspective

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap-cube

Sorry for the English translated by Google.

I created a cube in Analysis Services 2019 and from it some perspectives were created.

I would like a user to only be able to access a specific perspective only. Instead of this, the user visualizes all the cube and all perspectives.

[image: IMAGE: User view of the cubes and perspectives.]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you are using a Google Translator to post your question, this version of Stack Overflow might not be the right one for you, as it may mean that any answer you get you don't understand and so put back through said translator; that can easily result in misunderstandings or loss in translation.

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation. I don't know how to write, but my reading is reasonable. My hope is to at least be understood, to apply the solution I will do my best.

Answer (score 1):

Perspectives are not a security feature, so you can't do that. You'll have to use Row Level Security (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/roles-and-permissions-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions)